# Save Choice Filter Selection

Tags: list, web-part, filter, choice-field

I have four lists on a web page that I want to be controlled by a choice filter web part. The four lists have a common column between them, so I want users to be able to select an item in the choice filter to see what they need.

Is there a way to have the previous choice filter selection be saved every time a user navigates to the page? Right now, every time I reload the page I need to reenter the filter I want to use. It would be great it there was a way to save the previous selection and have that load when users navigate to the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could save the choice filter selection into a cookie with javascript, then read it on every page visit and set the choice filter value accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of to accomplish this OOTB would be to create another list rather than using a choice filter.  This way the users would be saving the same item instead of it reloading every time the page loads.

With this new list, create a choice field of the options you need like you would for the filter.  Then create one item in that list.  Use a list view web part on your page where you want the filtering done and have the view show just that one choice field (so essentially hide the title field).  Keep the quick edit link and use that to change the 'filter'.

With that set up you can use the connections between the web parts to filter on that field to your common field.

The downsides of this would be it is truly one list item for everyone, so there couldn't be too many people using this around the same time or you may get save errors.

To get by this you could set up a view in that list with an `Assigned To = [Me]` filter and give each user their own list item and have the connection run off of their list item that appears.