# Preserve all filter choices in a list when saving a new view with filters applied

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, filter, sharepoint-list-filter

**Problem:**

Let's say you have a column in a list with choices:

```
Red
Blue
Green
Yellow
```

Great. Now I want to filter the list items so that only Blue, Green, Yellow appear in the list. I do so.

After filtering and before saving the view, you can still select "Red" in the filter options. Great.

I save as a new view - and while the filters are saved in the view, I lose the "Red" choice when going back to change filters within that view. To see red list items, I would have to go back to the "All Items" view.

**Desired Solution:**

I want it so that I can pre-set filters for a view but preserve any choices that were not selected in that filter, like "Red", so that someone in that view can easily re-check a choice that was pre-set to be filtered out within that view.

Or in other words, save a view so that the filters selected remain checked, preserving the unchecked boxes.

To be even more clear, after saving a view, *instead of this* in the column filters:

```
[ ] Blue
[ ] Green
[ ] Yellow
```

*I want this* **after** saving a view:

```
[ ] Red
[X] Blue
[X] Green
[X] Yellow
```

Is this possible at all, or is this simply a hard limitation of SharePoint Lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of Sharepoint Lists, heres some work arounds you can try.

Save choice filter in a cookie with JS: [Save Choice Filter Selection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138581/save-choice-filter-selection)

Update the filter in specific views: [Updating SharePoint Filters in Specific Views](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306574/updating-sharepoint-filters-in-specific-views)

Finally you can try creating another list. This way, the users would be saving the same item instead of it reloading every time the page loads.